# std::string(empty char*) error: basic_string::_S_construct null not valid error

Tags: c++

On Debian, I need to read an environment variable, otherwise return an empty string. Here is my code:

```
std::string getEnv(std::string var)
{
    char* val = ::getenv(var.c_str());
    std::string retVal(val);
    return retVal;
}
```

When the environment variable is not found, I'm getting the following error:

```
basic_string::_S_construct null not valid error
```

After debugging, the error code happens on `std::string retVal(val)` when I try to load an empty val to it.

I tought loading an string from an empty `char *` would work, but seens not to.

How can I fix the above code so that I can make it work in case the enviroment variable does not exists ?

Comment: `val` will be null, and you can't pass null to the string constructor.

Comment: There is a difference between an empty string  "" and a null pointer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man getenv`:

> The `getenv()` function returns a pointer to the value in the environment, or `NULL` if there is no match.

So you need to account for the case where `val == NULL`.

```
std::string getEnv(std::string var)
{
    const char* val = ::getenv(var.c_str());
    if (val == nullptr)
        return std::string("");
    return std::string(val);
}
```

would be a possible solution (return empty string if var is not found).

Comment: If using C++17 then `std::optional<std::string>` could also be used as the return type which would make it clear that the `getEnv` function may fail to return a value.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option! Will have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: Great advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [string::data()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) function to get the address of underling buffer pointer.

try var.c_str() or var.data().

```
  std::string getEnv(std::string var)
    {
        char* val = ::getenv(var.data());
        std::string retVal(val ? val : "");
        return retVal;
    }
```

For me its working.

`val ? val : ""` to avoid passing NULL to `std::string()` constructor

Comment: Why do you need access to the raw data pointer? Doesn't sound like a good idea. Besides that, I don't really see a difference to my answer(?)

Comment: i prepared the answer and submitted late, yes .data() is raw pointer which can't be a good idea